# Зимняя ночь стала длиннее

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

Почему прилагательное "длиннее" используется в средном роде, а не женском? "длиннее" относится же к существительному женского рода - "ночь".

Comment: Разве  форма сравнительной степени может выражать значение рода? День стал длиннее, ночь стала длиннее. Род выражен глаголом-связкой (стал, стала).

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, как вы определили, что это именно средний род? Даже делая скидку на то, что у Вас русский - не родной, не могу понять, чем Вы руководствовались.

Comment: @behemothus Вы не можете понять потому, что Вы думаете своей головой. Имена прилагательные имеют окончания -ое, -ее и отвечают на вопрос какое?. И я забыл, а может и не додумался, что в предложении используется форма сравнительной степени.

Comment: @Sharon Нет, не может. Спасибо!

Comment: @UlugbekUmbarov  Да без проблем, это понятно, тут действительно тонкость имеется. То есть получается, Вы просто неверно задали вопрос к слову "длиннее". Оно не отвечает на вопрос "какое?", оно отвечает на вопрос "(стала) какой?". Но проблема в том, что и этот вопрос не совсем точный. Спасибо, я эту тему разобью отдельным вопросом,

Comment: Загляните сюда, возможно Вам тоже будет интересно обещанное развитие темы. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, но на вопрос Ваш невозможно ответить. *Вообще советую избегать вопросов, начинающихся с "почему"*. Но у вас еще и посылка в корне неверная. Здесь нет ни женского, ни среднего рода. Вообще такие формы, называемые сравнительными прилагательными, не имеют категории рода. ***Это не "средний род", это форма употребляемая со всеми родами.*** Лингвисты, говоря об "отстутствии категории рода", имеют в виду именно это.

*Могу только на примерах это продемонстрировать.

Этот банан вкуснее (чем тот).

Это яблоко вкуснее (чем тот).

Эта груша вкуснее (чем та).

Эти сливы вкуснее (чем те).

Этот чемодан легче. Эта сумка тяжелее. Эти ученики умнее.*
Нигде и никогда такие формы не имеют категории рода.

*Грамматический род, правда, присутствует в полностью синонимичных высказываниях с так называемой **аналитической** формой сравнительной степени (противопоставляемой разбираемой, которую называют **"синтетической"**) - "Этот банан более вкусный", "Эта груша более вкусная" - и т. д., но они вопросов не вызывают.*