# Грамматический вопрос к сравнительной степени прилагательного/причастия

Tags: грамматика

Учили нас, что любой член предложения отвечает на какой-то определенный вопрос, который и определяет грамматику данного члена предложения.

Из обсуждения в теме [Зимняя ночь стала длиннее](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461876): ***Ночь стала длиннее.***

Какой вопрос связывает "стала" и "длиннее"?
На вопрос "какой?" отвечает форма "длинная", это не то, путает.  А "какова" не совсем подходит по смыслу. Но беда даже не в этом. Обе эти формы - "(стала) какой" и "какова" - имеют категорию грамматического рода, которой нет у сравнительного прилагательного (в синтетической форме).
Нет ли здесь какого-то скрытого противоречия?! Или, может, "правильный" вопрос всё же существует?

*ПС Слова "каковее" в русском, увы, нет. А оно бы подошло.*

@Людмила

> Нет степеней сравнения у причастия, только у прилагательного и у
> наречия.

Это совершенно не принципиальный для меня вопрос, но вы вводите нас в заблуждение. Ограничусь только одной цитатой

> 3. Ограниченно употребительны формы сравнит. степени: а)
>    прилагательных, мотивированных глаголами, с суф. -л-, типа бывалый,
>    впалый, позеленелый, захудалый, онемелый, отвислый (см. § 662); б)
>    ***причастий в адъективном знач. с суф. -ущ-, -ащ-, -|о|м- и -т-:*** а)
>    Самый берег казался пустынней и одичалей - и только (Тург.); Ему очень
>    захотелось спора, в котором он вышел бы и умнее, и толковее, и бывалее
>    Салтыка (Бунин); Это тень твоя стала такой – Еще старше и осатанелей
>    (Анток.); б) Женщины умнее и любящее (В. Белинский); Твой взор
>    открытей и бесстрашней (Фет); Пусть блестящее, чем свет, Два блистают
>    черных глаза (В. Хлебников); Но есть иные люди. Те Еще несчастней и
>    забытей (Есен.); На рисунке все формы типичнее, подчеркнутее (газ.).
>
> ***Примечание. От причастий на -енный, -анный в адъективном значении
> формы сравнит. степени образуются свободно:*** Дорога стала тяжелее и
> засыпаннее (Л. Толст.): И ты знаешь, что нас разлученней В этом мире
> никто не бывал (Ахм.); Солнце выше, воздух суше, Растревоженней базар
> (Солоух.).

АГ-80, курсив мой.
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1342-1365.html, § 1344, п. 3).

> 

(++)
@Sharon

> Что касается вопроса «каковее», то форма сравнительной степени
> прилагательного – это неизменяемая форма, которая не может выражать
> грамматические значения (род, например), поэтому и нет этого слова в
> языке.

Вот этого я совсем не понимаю. При чем тут неизменяемая форма вообще?
Кстати, неизменяемой является только синтетическая форма сравнительной степени, аналитическая вполне себе изменяется. Но даже для синтетической формы, что следует из этой неизменяемости?
(+++)
@Sharon (и все), давайте я в лоб спрошу. **Вы признаете, что не ко всякому слову в предложении можно подобрать правильный вопрос?** Если да, к каким именно можно/нельзя - и как это объяснить школьнику?!
(++++)
Людмила что-то такое говорила про члены предложения, но вилами по воде писано. Когда мы задаем вопрос (вернее - как учат его задавать), то он ставится так, что "Какой вопрос надо задать к этому слову?" - именно для того, чтобы понять, каким членом предложение является это слово.
То есть в школьном синтаксисе вопрос - первичен. А член предложения уже устанавливается на основании этого вопроса.
Вот эту нестыковку я и хочу с вашей помощью разрулить.

Answer (score 1):

***Ночь стала длиннее.***  Это составное именное сказуемое, именная часть выражена сравнительной степень прилагательного

1. **Какой вопрос можно задать  к сказуемому и  к его к именной части?**

1.1. **Ночь длинна.** – Ночь (каковА?) длиннА.

Вопрос соотносится с формой краткого прилагательного и выражает значение рода.

1.2. **Ночь стала более длинной**. – Ночь (что сделалА?) сталА. –  Стала (какОЙ?)  более длиннОЙ.

Все вопросы вполне логичны по семантике  и имеют соответствующую по роду и падежу грамматическую форму.

1.3. **Ночь стала  длиннее.** –  Ночь (что сделалА?) сталА. –  Стала (какОЙ?)  длиннее.

Для нас естественно слышать именно этот вопрос, так как  варианты  «длиннее»  и  «более длинная» **равнозначны по смыслу,** поэтому мы используем один и тот же вопрос «какой».

Что касается вопроса «каковее», то форма сравнительной степени прилагательного – это неизменяемая форма, которая не может выражать грамматические значения (род, например), поэтому и нет этого слова в языке.

2. **Можно ли считать, что общим вопросом  для признакового  именного сказуемого являются вопросы «каков, какова, каково»?**

***Каковой*** (устар. и спец.)  – ***каков*** (краткая форма).

Основное различие полной и краткой формы по Виноградову:

https://scicenter.online/yazyik-russkiy-scicenter/russkiy-yazyik-grammaticheskoe-uchenie-slove.html

«Выражение **постоянного**, мыслимого вне ограничений времени признака — основная функция имени прилагательного. Значение качественного состояния, мыслимого в формах **времени**, уже несколько выходит за пределы имени прилагательного. Полные прилагательные даже в предикативном употреблении обозначают, что признак в предмете пребывает постоянно, что существование признака охватывает весь период бытия предмета.
Напротив, краткие прилагательные выражают, что признак в предмете пребывает непостоянно, является **временным** его состоянием».

Задавая вопрос  «каков», мы подчеркиваем  процессуальность признака, выраженного сказуемым, то есть **временное состояние**. Поэтому при возможности этот вопрос применяется, но при этом он должен вписываться в речевую ситуацию.

Мы можем сказать: ночь (какова?)  длинна,  скорость ветра (какова?) – 4 метра в секунду, но **вряд ли корректно** будет звучать такая фраза: Ночь (какова?) стала длиннее.  Небо (каково?) кажется близким. В этих случаях вопросы **надо дифференцировать.** Стоит учесть, что **речевая несочетаемость** – это очень серьезная стилистическая погрешность.

А это пример того, как пользователи пытаются ответить на этот вопрос https://znanija.com/task/8793845

Comment: *Это составное именное сказуемое, именная часть выражена сравнительной степень прилагательного* - вы переиначили мой вопрос. От слова "стала" к слове "длинне" можно задать вопрос или нет? Что до именного сказуемого, то вопрос обычно задается чем? (ночь "[стала] днем") или "какой?" (ночь [стала] темной). Поэтому даже нсли предполагать тут именно СИС, то должен быть вопрос естественный ("каковее?"), но его нет.

Comment: *Что касается вопроса «каковее», то форма сравнительной степени прилагательного – это неизменяемая форма, которая не может выражать грамматические значения (род, например), поэтому и нет этого слова в языке.* - простите, но это выше моего понимания. Неужнли вы считаеете, что вопросы задают только к изменяемым формам? Наречие тоже форма неизменяемая, но вопрос к ней (как?) известен любому школьнику.

Comment: *Основное различие полной и краткой формы по Виноградову:* - а что в этой теме вообще краткая форма делает?

Comment: *Для нас естественно слышать именно этот вопрос, так как варианты «длиннее» и «более длинная» равнозначны по смыслу, * - а кто возражает? Более длинная - такая же сравнительная степень, только выраженная аналитически. И к ней точно также невозможно подобрать "правильный" вопрос. Разве что "более какой?". Но вряд ли его примут в школе...

Comment: Более длиннАЯ (какАЯ) - это как бы  "правильный вопрос", одинаковые окончания прилагательного.  "Каков" - краткая форма, а краткие формы имеют  временное значение признака, как и сказуемое. Поэтому при возможности вопрос "каков" задается для составного именного сказуемого (ночь каковА? - длиннА).  Вопросы задают по разным причинам, например чтобы определить падеж слова. Также по вопросу определяют синтаксическую роль слова. Части речи также имеют свой основной вопрос (предметный или признаковый).

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый behemothus, Вы нас специально запутываете, чтобы затеять грамматическую дикуссию?

Во-первых, странность в названии вопроса: "Грамматический вопрос к сравнительной степени прилагательного/причастия". Нет степеней сравнения у причастия, только у прилагательного и у наречия.

Во-вторых, в зачине вопроса речь о члене предложения, а суть его относится к размышлению о части речи. Что именно Вас интересует?

В-третьих, с какой целью Вы ищете "правильный" вопрос к слову? Чтобы выбрать верное окончание? Верный род? Это невозможно, потому что верное окончание по вопросу мы выбираем **только в косвенных** падежах прилагательных, в нашем примере речь идёт совсем не об этом. Нет косвенных падежей у сравнительной степени, нет и родов - это неизменяемая форма.
Вернёмся к её грамматической сути.

Степень сравнения - это **один из непостоянных признаков** прилагательного (и наречия).

В русском языке существуют три степени сравнения прилагательных:

1. положительная степень (исходная). Обозначает признак предмета без сравнения с другими объектами (какой? - Теплый, зеленый)
2. сравнительная степень. Признак предмета градуируется, можно говорить о степени проявления данного признака путем сравнения (Это какая трава по сравнению с другой? - Зеленее; Эта комната какая в сравнении с другой? -  Теплее).
3. превосходная степень. Признак предмета проявлен в своей наивысшей точке (самая зеленая трава; самая теплая комната).

   ```
       Какой вопрос связывает "стала" и "длиннее"? На вопрос "какой?" 
       отвечает форма "длинная", это не то, путает. А "какова" не совсем подходит по 
       смыслу. Но беда даже не в этом. Обе эти формы - "(стала) какой" и "какова" - 
       имеют категорию грамматического рода, которой нет у сравнительного 
       прилагательного (в синтетической форме). Нет ли здесь какого-то скрытого 
       противоречия?
   ```

Не вижу никаких противоречий. Если нам нужно поставить вопрос к члену предложения сказуемому, мы ставим **вопрос именного сказуемого:** Ночь какова? Что говорится о ночи?

Если устанавливать связь внутри слитного сочетания стала длиннее, там **вопрос не имеет значения, потому что прилагательное **примыкает**** к глаголу, оно неизменяемое: стала какова? стала какой? стала какая? Все вопросы корректны.

Так что автору предыдущего вопроса Вы вряд ли поможете своими изысканиями, он просто перепутал положительную (исходную) степень прилагательного и сравнительную, чисто грамматическая ошибка. Не допускать её получится, только умея видеть сравнительную степень и зная, что она неизменяемая и потому не имеет рода. Никаких вопросов задавать не нужно.

Для сравнительной степени указание на связь с сущ. не является актуальным. (число и род не влияет на форму сравн. ст: Волга шире Днепра; Волга шире других рек).

Но если обратиться к истории формы сравнительной степени, то мы увидим искомую  связь. О тенденции к утрате сравнительной степенью согласовательных форм и преобразованию ее в неизменяемую форму с предикативной специализацией можно прочитать в учебниках и научных статьях по лингвистике.

> История развития сравнительной степени, имея в виду ее краткую форму,
> заключалась в том, что, так же как и краткие прилагательные, она
> перестала употребляться в роли определения и потому потеряла
> способность к словоизменению (потеря форм словоизменения сравнительной
> степенью начинает отражаться в памятниках с XII в.), застыв в одной
> определенной форме. **Наиболее продуктивной в истории оказалась бывшая
> форма имен. пад. ед. ч. ср. р. на -эе > -ее или с редукцией конечного
> ч гласного -ей:** ср. современное скорее с др.-русск. **муж. р. скорэе,
> ср. р.- скорее, жен. р. скорэиши;** современное сильнее — с др.-русск.
> муж. р. сильней, ср. р. сильнее, жен. р. сильнэиши.
> В диалектах, а
> также в просторечии формы на -ее, -ей распространены шире, чем в
> литературном языке: ср. хужее, тужее, жарчее, прощее, ближей, тишей н
> т. п. (лит. хуже, туже восходят также к имен. пад. ед. ч. ср. р.). **Что
> касается таких форм, как больше, меньше, то они по происхождению
> являются формой имен. пад. мн. ч, муж. р.**
>
> Специально следует сказать о
> судьбе форм с основой на заднеязычный согласный типа кратъчае,
> крэпъчае, свежае, ловъчае. Некоторые из них были вытеснены формами на
> -е под влиянием таких образований, как хуже, туже, больше, меньше; другие же попали под влияние наиболее распространенных форм на -ее,
> например, свежее, ловчее (ср. обратный процесс в диалектах, в
> результате которого там развиваются формы вроде сильняе, здоровяе и т.
> п.). Гласный [а] после шипящего сохранился лишь в полных формах типа
> кратчайший, нижайший, высочайший, крепчайший и т. д. Однако эти полные
> формы, сохранив полностью способность различаться по родам, числам и
> падежам, вместе с тем изменили свое значение: если первоначально они
> были формами сравнительной степени, то в истории русского языка они
> получили значение превосходной степени. Полные формы на -эйш, -айш
> сохраняли значение сравнительной степени еще в XIX в.; так, они
> употребляются, например, в переводе Жуковским «Одиссеи»: огромнейший
> первого камень схватил, или у Тургенева: я легкомысленно разбил сосуд,
> в тысячу раз драгоценнейший. https://studopedia.info/5-103338.html

А вопрос как был каков? какова? каково?, так и остался.

Comment: Насчет причастия - не принципиально. Это старый разговор про разделекние этих частей речи. У отглагольного прилагательного ср. ст. точно существует, по крайней мере в разговоре. "Вы сегодня еще более расстроен(н)ы текущими событиями, чем вчера". Вы можете поручиться, что здесь не причастие, а прилагательное?! Я -- нет.

Comment: *Если нам нужно поставить вопрос к члену предложения сказуемому, мы ставим вопрос именного сказуемого. - Простите, но: 1.  на вопрос какова отвечает форма "длинна", а не длиннее. 2. Вопрос надо задвать от слова "стала", а не "ночь". Не находите? Или я чего не понимаю в школьном синтаксисе?

Comment: *Вы нас специально запутываете, чтобы затеять грамматическую дикуссию?* - Ни Боже мой. Я рад буду любой содержательной дискуссии, но умышленно путать никого не собираюсь. Хотя и в том не вижу ничего предосудительного. Метод ad absurdum, полагаю, вам известен.  Остально попробую осмыслить, пока создается впечатление, что вы либо не понялм вопроса, либо занимаетесь тем, в чем меня обвинили, то есть умышленно наводите тень на плетень.

Comment: ПС *Что именно Вас интересует?* - меня интересует вопрос к тому члену предложения, который представлен в моем примере частью речи "длиннее". Неужели непонятно?

Comment: *с какой целью Вы ищете "правильный" вопрос к слову?* - из академического интереса.

Comment: *там вопрос не имеет значения, потому что прилагательное примыкает к глаголу* - вы рискнете это повторить на уроке ученикам, которым с первого по одиннадцатый вдалбливали, что любой любой член предложения отвечает на какой-то конкретный вопрос? И не потому, что в этом вопросе есть какая высшая цель, а потому что таков синтаксис русского (да и любого другого) языка?

Comment: Ну да, вопрос есть, и мы его задали - ночь какова? или стала какова? Единственно верный вопрос, только в данном случае он не устанавливает согласование (или координацию) в роде, потому что сравнительная степень - неизменяемая форма, но когда-то была изменяемой, сейчас добавлю в ответ, в комментарии места не хватит.

Comment: "Какова" не проходит, потому, что это вопрос к другой форме. Ночь какова - ночь длинна. Дело не в неизменяемости, а в синтаксисе.

Comment: Ну, в синтаксисе изменение одно - раньше сравнительная степень была определением, а стала сказуемым.

Comment: @Людмила  Я вот тоже не понимаю, почему вопрос  КАКОВА считается универсальным для именного сказуемого: ночь (каковА?) - длиннА, ночь какАЯ? - длиннАЯ, ночь стала какОЙ - длиннОЙ. По-моему, так логичнее, так как окончания совпадают. А в некоторых случаях КАКОВА вообще не походит, например: ночь кажется длинной. Откуда это правило про универсальный вопрос? У ж лучше спросить: что говорится про ночь, если вопрос не подходит.

Comment: В моём ответе: " стала какова? стала какой? стала какая? Все вопросы корректны". Этого оказалось недостаточно.

Comment: Вопрос "стала какова" кажется некорректным, мы же не говорим: стала длинна.

Comment: *мы увидим искомую связь* - Спасибо, конечно, но я не ищу этой связи. Совсем простой вопрос вопрос: ***Почему вы считаете, что "длиннее" отвечает на вопрос "какая/какой/какае?"*** ----- Добро бы  еще было "подлиннее" - эту форму еще можно с грехом пополам засунуть вне исходной предикативности:  *дайте мне палку (какую?) подлиннее* . Но почему  *стала какой? - длиннее* - этого я понять не могу.